# Features Recognition from STEP file

Tags: python, cad

Are there any methods to extract features such as a blind hole, a through hole, curve and so on from a STEP file (CAD File) and print them like this :

- Feature no. 1 : Through Hole
- The Length (mm) : 10
- The Radius (mm) : 20.

Comment: Do you mean reading the STEP file from a program? Or from a CAD system API?

Comment: I have written a python script to read an existing STEP file(.stp file) and the exactly my question is how I can parse the file and extract useful information to recognize the features (holes, planes, ..etc) automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Cylinders can be defined in a number of ways, for example a) revolving a line around an axis b) as cylindrical surface c) as nurbs/generic surface, etc. If you are lucky enough, you can identify all the holes as CYLINDRICAL_SURFACEs. The depth/length is a different matter. You need to compute it between the two planar faces (PLANE) adjacent to the cylindrical one and here things become complicated because you need to rebuild the adjacency graph of all faces.

For more information you can check:

1. [CYLINDRICAL_SURFACE](http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/ifc/IFC2x4/alpha/html/ifcgeometryresource/lexical/ifccylindricalsurface.htm)
2. [PLANE](http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/ifc/IFC2x3/TC1/html/ifcgeometryresource/lexical/ifcplane.htm)